# how do i add new obj in an array in localStorage everytime I submit my form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how do i add new obj in an array in localStorage in ReactJS everytime I submit my form?

the issue is ,it is updating everytime in hit sumbit ,i want results to [{1},{2},...]

Comment: Where is the code that you have attempted to do?

Comment: Can you edit the question and [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and share the code of what has been done so far to solve it. Please note that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

When u want to save variable to local storage :

localStorage.setItem("test",JSON.stringify([{username:"John",password:"123"}]))

Then :

```
  const lclStrg= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"))
  lclStrg.push({username:"Mohammad",password:"321"})
  localStorage.setItem('form',JSON.stringify(lclStrg))
```

So when u save the form the code should be as following :
let formInfo={
username:"micheal",
password:"123456"
}
if(lclStrg.getItem("form")){
const lclStrg= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"))
lclStrg.push(formInfo)
localStorage.setItem('form',JSON.stringify(lclStrg))
}
else{
localStorage.setItem("form",JSON.stringiy([formInfo])
}

```
  //formInfo is the value submitted by the form
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this code:
I have printed the values before adding a new item and after adding a new item to the `localStorage`

```
let data = localStorage.getItem("form_data")

console.log(data)

let formdata = {
  "name": "Nidhey",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "phone": "11111111"
}

if(data == null){
  data = []
  data.push(formdata)
  localStorage.setItem("form_data", JSON.stringify([formdata]))
}else{
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  data.push({
     "name": "John",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "phone": "11111111"
  })
  localStorage.setItem("form_data", JSON.stringify(data))
}

console.log(data)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Nidhey",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "phone": "11111111"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "phone": "11111111"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "phone": "11111111"
    }
]
```